# How is a navigation controller added to an existing view

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a tableView and want to add a new viewController so that when the user selects an item the new view shows an image and the bar at the top will allow the user to go back to the tableView.

This navigation bar at the top will be present in both views. Is it also possible to add a button e.g. share to it and link my own actions to the button?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tableView should live inside a UIViewController subclass that is itself inside of a UINavigationController.   You can get this structure set up for you by selecting the "navigation-based" app in the project creation wizard.   Or you can create this structure yourself in code.   In your app delegate, create a UINavigationController, and set your app's first ViewController as the root view controller.   Then pushing and popping view controllers is easy, just call:

```
MyDetailVC *vc = [[[MyDetailVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyDetailVC" bundle:nil] autorelease];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

EDIT: so, to clarify, you don't "add navigation controllers to existing views," you "push and pop instances of your view controllers on to the navigation controller's stack."

Comment: What is self here? Does each view controller need to have a navigation controller?

Comment: each view controller pushed on to the UINavigationController stack will have its navigationController property set up automatically by the UINavigationController